# Saving result from AND operation in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm

How can I save the result from performed AND operation. 
For example, if myString has the value "a", how can I AND this with 6 and save the result into EAX for example?

```
AND myString, 6 
mov eax, result ;how to get result?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov eax, 6
mov ebx, mystring
and eax, ebx
mov result, eax
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer got me going. Thanks again.